# How to interact with Python's objects through GUI (GTK)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, user-interface, gtk3

For example, my program heavily relies on working with 2D numpy arrays, and I need to visualize it and consequently allow the user to change its contents.

**My GUI:**

[image: My GUI]

I choose GTK to start with, but does it even has an option to do so? If not, what's the alternative graphics library? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list store and then append each row. e.g if you have a numpy array you can convert it to a list. Below is the approach that can be of use to you.
if you have an array

```
test_array = [[1,2,3].[4,5,6]]
```

Then you can save it to a liststore like.

```
array_list_store = Gtk.ListStore(int, int, int)
for row in test_array:
    array_list_store.append(row.tolist())
```

if you want to update liststore values you can do so in similar manner as in list or array.

```
array_list_store[0][1] = 10
```

This will set the 2nd element of 1st row equal to 10.